# WTForms checkbox field not populating

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I'm fairly new to Python & Flask in general, but I'm having an issue with checkboxes that I can't figure out.  Database field is an Integer (SQLite).  When I create a record, it works with 1 or 0.  However, when I try to edit a record using WTForms, I can't get the checkbox to reflect what is in the database - 1 or 0 (Checked or Unchecked).  The fields in question below are manager, dept_head, and admin.  Not sure what I'm missing?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

- Apologies for the wall of text, but wanted to make sure I didn't leave anything out.

Model

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'users'

id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
firstname       = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
lastname        = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
email           = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
password_hash   = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
locationid      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('locations.id'), nullable=True)
location        = db.relationship('Location', backref='users')
departmentid    = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'), nullable=True)
department      = db.relationship('Department', backref='users')
job_title       = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
mobile_phone    = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
manager         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
dept_head       = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
admin           = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
date_created    = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_updated    = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_deleted    = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

Form

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
id              = HiddenField('ID')
firstname       = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
lastname        = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
email           = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
locationid      = SelectField('Location')
departmentid    = SelectField('Department')
job_title       = StringField('Job Title')
mobile_phone    = StringField('Mobile Phone', validators=[DataRequired()])
manager         = BooleanField('Manager', default=False, false_values=(False, 'false', 0, '0'))
dept_head       = BooleanField('Dept Head', default=False, false_values=(False, 'false', 0, '0'))
admin           = BooleanField('Admin', default=False, false_values=(False, 'false', 0, '0'))
submit          = SubmitField('Create')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__()
    self.locationid.choices = [(l.id, l.name) for l in Location.query.all()]
    self.departmentid.choices = [(d.id, d.name) for d in Department.query.all()]
```

Controller

```
@mod_user.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit(id):
u = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
form = UserForm()
form.process(formdata=request.form, obj=u)
return render_template('user/edit.html', form=form, u = u)
```

Edit.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('user.update', id=u.id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="UserForm">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.id }}
<p><label>First Name: </label>{{ form.firstname(class_='form-control') }}</p>
<p><label>Last Name: </label>{{ form.lastname(class_='form-control') }}</p>
<p><label>Email: </label>{{ form.email(class_='form-control') }}</p>
<p><label>Location: </label>{{ form.locationid(class_='form-control') }}</p>
<p><label>Dept: </label>{{ form.departmentid(class_='form-control') }}</p>
<p><label>Job Title: </label>{{ form.job_title(class_='form-control') }}</p>
<p><label>Mobile Phone: </label>{{ form.mobile_phone(class='form-control', placeholder='(555) 555-1212') }}</p>
<p><label>Manager: </label>{{ form.manager(class_='fancy-checkbox', value=1) }}</p>
<p><label>Dept Head: </label>{{ form.dept_head(class_='fancy-checkbox', value=1) }}</p>
<p><label>Admin: </label>{{ form.admin(class_='fancy-checkbox', value=1) }}</p>
{{ form.submit(class_='btn btn-primary btn-lg') }}
</form>
```

Data
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv6ts.png)

Form in Action (Admin user example, all should be checked)
[Web Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVDOh.png)

Comment: Why did you define admin and dept_head as integers and not as booleans? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Boolean

Comment: Because SQLite doesn't have a boolean datatype per their v3 documentation - unless I'm reading it wrong?  New to SQLite also, so that could be the issue.

Comment: You can absolutely declare it as db.Boolean, however under the hood it is still an integer. But this will tell python to deal with the field as True/False

Comment: The first link I posted comes from SQLAlchemy's own docs, this is from flask-sqlalchemy http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/

Comment: Ok - that makes sense, thank you.  I've changed them to db.Boolean, and it works in the console sending True, True, True when creating a User object.  But when I do it through Edit.html, I get an typeError:  '1' is not a boolean value.  Have tried value=1 and value=True on the checkbox field. 

Seems that it's sending value=True or value=1 as a string?